# Shutil multiple files after reading with "pydicom"

Tags: python, pydicom

What I basicalling want is for myvar to vary between 1-280 so that I can use this to read the file using pydicom. I.e. I want to read the files between /data/lfs2/model-mie/inputDataTest/subj2/mp2rage/**0-280**_tfl3d1.IMA. Then if M is true in gender then I want to shutil them into a folder. Doesnt seem to be working with count.

Thanks for the help!

```
 from pydicom import dicomio
myvar = str(count(0))
import shutil
file = "/data/lfs2/model-mie/inputDataTest/subj2/mp2rage/" + myvar + "_tfl3d1.IMA"
ds = dicomio.read_file(file)

gender = ds.PatientSex
print(gender)
if gender == "M":
    shutil.copy(file, "/mnt/nethomes/s4232182/Desktop/New")
```

Answer (score 1):

I think the `range()` function should do what you want, something like this:

```
import shutil
from pydicom import dicomio

for i in range(281):
    filename = "/data/lfs2/model-mie/inputDataTest/subj2/mp2rage/" + str(i) + "_tfl3d1.IMA"
    ds = dicomio.read_file(filename)
    if ds.get('PatientSex') == "M":
        shutil.copy(filename, "/mnt/nethomes/s4232182/Desktop/New" )
```

I've also used `ds.get()` to avoid problems if the dataset does not contain a PatientSex data element.

In one place in your question, the numbering is 1-280, in another it is 0-280.  If the former, then use `range(1, 281)` instead.